# How to add multiple BPEL processes from same BPEL project to CApp

Tags: wso2, bpel

When im trying to create a CApp which includes multiple BPEL process we are not ebing given a provision to select the BPEL process in CApp.. Please refer to the screen shot below. How can we get out of this..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per your screen shot you need to list all the process on the Carbon Application POM Editor.Let me explain that the purpose of Carbon Application POM Editor, it is used to list the all the deployable artifacts so user can decide what should be packaged in to CAR and what to not. So the editor dose not intended to show the processes one by one. In the DSS scenario currently you can not have multiple data service in single data service project.

Comment: Agreed on it.. But, here i have two bpel processes which i have to deploy onto BPS server. Now from the screen shot its just provisioning to deploy only one BPEL process. Please let me know how can i deploy another BPEL process using this CAR application approach ?

Comment: For your scenario, the best solution is to have two different BPEL projects and add those two projects into the CApp, rather than having two BPEL files in the same BPEL project. If you have two BPEL files in the same BPEL project, then you need to make sure that deploy.xml is updated accordingly.

Comment: That is always possible... But now if i have a scenario where i have a single BPEL project which groups multiple BPEL processes and wish to deploy all of them as if like a simple car application. How can i go with this scenario ?

Comment: If you see the image i have provided i have created EMPBPEL and that is the only one BPEL process being listed in Carbon Artifacts. Please help

Comment: As Kalpa has mensioned, Carbon Application pom just shows the project names. Here you have only one BPEL Project (thats why you see only one bpel project in the pom) and that project has two bpel files. pom only lists the projects not bpel files. Therefore the behaviour is correct. if you have implemented the BPEL files and the deploy.xml correctly, both of your BPEL processes should get deployed without a problem.

Comment: Oh got it now.. Sorry for the confusion.. as i choose both the project and BPEL name as same. im assuming that its the BPEL process that is being listed.. Thanks a ton for your help.